# Stripe Connect Oauth does not take Business name as account name

Tags: stripe-payments

Hi all I am following Stripe Connect Oauth link and created url where I prefill business’s url and business name

https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=ca_xxxxxx&response_type=code&scope=read_write&stripe_user%5Bemail%5D=Tt@yahoo.com&stripe_user%5Bphone_number%5D=4543312&stripe_user%5Bcountry%5D=US&stripe_user%5Bbusiness_name%5D=ABCD&stripe_user%5Bbusiness_type%5D=individual&stripe_user%5Bfirst_name%5D=Tom&stripe_user%5Blast_name%5D=Service&stripe_user%5Burl%5D=https://www.google.com&state=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://xxxxx

As you can see I specified the url as https://www.google.com and the business name as ABCD

However, after the stripe connect account is created, the account name becomes “www.google”, how come Stripe just trunk part of business url as the account name? At least it should use the business name I provided, correct?

Comment: Where did you see the business name wrong - in the stripe dashboard or in a payment information ? I had personally faced the issue of wrong business name, but then it was about providing info to stripe on what need to be displayed on billing info.

Comment: In stripe dashboard, where you can see the stripe connect accounts created under your stripe platform account, click on one of those connect account, then checkout the name of the account.